# VBA outlook new mail

Tags: vba, outlook

I am trying to run a function every time a new mail arrives in outlook. I have been doing some searching but I am unable to find I way to fire code every time an email arrives. Is there a new mail event that I could utilize?

I added a simple `MsgBox` to it to be able to see if the event is firing but it did not seem to be working. I placed this code in the `ThisOutlookSession` module. Any adivice? Here is my code.

```
   Public WithEvents myOlApp As Outlook.Application

    Sub Initialize_handler()
        Set myOlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    End Sub

    Private Sub myOlApp_NewMail()
        Dim myExplorers As Outlook.Explorers
        Dim myFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
        Dim x As Integer
        Set myExplorers = myOlApp.Explorers
        Set myFolder = myOlApp.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
        If myExplorers.Count <> 0 Then
            For x = 1 To myExplorers.Count
                On Error GoTo skipif
                If myExplorers.Item(x).CurrentFolder.Name = "Inbox" Then
                    MsgBox ("Test")
                    myExplorers.Item(x).Display
                    myExplorers.Item(x).Activate
                    Exit Sub
                End If
    skipif:
            Next x
         End If
         On Error GoTo 0
         myFolder.Display
    End Sub
```

Comment: When someone has provided an answer that solved your problem, mark it as accepted by clicking the little V next to the answer. This way, you signal to anyone reading this that this is the solution, and that your problem has been solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to put:

```
Private Sub Application_NewMail()
    MsgBox "New mail"
End Sub
```

In "ThisOutlookSession"

Comment: Thanks Matt. This worked on my work computer, but sadly not on my home computer... the one I am trying to develop for. I clearly have a deeper rooted problem with outlook. This will take some more digging.

Comment: well this is embarrassing. This whole time I had macros disabled in outlook. I am looking forward to actually moving forward with this project. Thanks to all for the help!

Comment: @loveforvdubs If Matt's answer helped you solve it, you should select it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

There's a good example on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa171307%28v=office.11%29.aspx) showing how to display the inbox when a new mail arrives (using `Outlook.Explorers`).  You can probably adapt it pretty readily for your own program.

Comment: @loveforvdubs You should probably edit your question to indicate what you have tried, what results you expected, and what results you got.

Comment: sorry I didn't mean to submit that comment earlier, please see below

Comment: Is there a way to post code in a comment? I have been trying to reply with the code I tried using but I have been unable to find a way to post code in the comment field.

Comment: @loveforvdubs There is an `Edit` link below your question. Use that do open the question in edit mode and add your code. If you have a small snippet, use backticks in a comment to give it a bit of code formatting.

Comment: @loveforvdubs You can edit your original post and put the code there (it's possible to paste it in comments, but there's no formatting)

Comment: @Steve In sync here, I guess? hehe.